# How to get 4 inputs from an input box

Tags: vb.net

I've created a form that I want it to control course registration process.

So my codes are as follows

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim InpName As String

For i = 1 To 4
    InpName = InputBox("What course do you want to register")
    If InpName = "computer literacy" Then
        TextBox1.Text = InpName
    ElseIf InpName = "engineering" Then
        TextBox1.Text = InpName
    Else
        MsgBox("We only offer computer literacy and engineering")
    End If
Next i
```

I want the loop to accept computer literacy or engineering 4 times and tell a user that computer literacy course or engineering course is full.

Comment: Thats looks like horrible usabillity. Why not use a dropdown List?
Also, I am not sure if you really need a loop in this place. You probably should add a "engieering" and a "Literacy" Variable, which are incremented each time somebody registers for a course.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim InpName As String
        Dim engineering As Integer = 0
        Dim compLit As Integer = 0
        For i = 1 To 4
                InpName = InputBox("What course do you want to register")
                If InpName = "computer literacy" Then
                    compLit = compLit + 1
                    TextBox1.Text = InpName
                ElseIf InpName = "engineering" Then
                    engineering = engineering + 1
                    TextBox1.Text = InpName
                Else
                    MsgBox("We only offer computer literacy and engineering")
                End If

            If compLit = 4 Then
                MsgBox("Computer Literacy is full!")
            ElseIf engineering = 4 Then
                MsgBox("Engineering is full!")
            End If
        Next
```

I wanted to add an explanation of what is happening here. Two variables engineering and compLit are created and given a 0 value on the button click. The loop happens and each time one of their values is correctly inputted, those variables increment by 1. At the end of each loop, the values are checked to see if they are 4 and the associated message is displayed. If either are not 4, then no message since the classes are not full.

Comment: I've decided to use a label that display 4 when  my form is loaded, and when a user enters computer literacy in the input box the counter is reduced by on until 0, when the label counter is at 0, a message box is displayed telling a user that a counter is full and the the button is disabled. The problem is this

Comment: You never said what the problem is, I am not sure how to help you.